# Highchart column range with hour

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart in order to show a range of hour for each day. In other words, I'd like to make something like this : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/, but with hours informations instead of temperature.
I've made this code (https://paste.maxux.net/x61fKlc), but the system doesn't draw the bars.

Can someone explain how to do this? Thanks for your time.

```
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['01/01/2000', '02/01/2000', '03/01/2000', '04/01/2000', '05/01/2000', '06/01/2000', '07/01/2000']
        },
        yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Heure'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                    dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                    return (this.y.getHours()+1) + ':' + (this.y.getMinutes());
                            }
                    }
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Working hours',
            data: [
                            [Date(0,0,0, 12,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 15,00,00)],
                            [Date(0,0,0, 13,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 16,00,00)],
                            [Date(0,0,0, 14,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 17,00,00)],
                            [Date(0,0,0, 13,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 15,00,00)],
                            [Date(0,0,0, 13,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 15,00,00)],
                            [Date(0,0,0, 13,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 15,00,00)],
                            [Date(0,0,0, 13,00,00), new Date(0,0,0, 15,00,00)]
        ]
        }]

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) instead of just `Date` -- it'll return a number (which I believe is what you can use in a column range); second, to display that correctly, change the formatter to create a date object from the milliseconds which are now the data:

```
formatter: function () {
    var d = new Date(this.y);
    return return d.getHours() + ':' + (d.getMinutes());
}
```

Check the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/pgvUL/).